# Trying to upload a file to firebase storage using pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I have been working on an app and have discovered accessing firebase storage using pyrebase.

```
import pyrebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "API",
  "authDomain": "DOMAIN",
  "databaseURL": "URL",
  "projectId": "ID",
  "storageBucket": "STORE_BUCKET",
  "messagingSenderId": "SEND_ID",
  "appId": "APP_ID",
  "serviceAccount": "PATH_TO_KEY"
}

firebase_storage = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase_storage.storage()
storage = firebase_storage.storage()
storage.child("IMAGE.jpeg").put("IMAGE.jpeg")
```

I have been able to successfully upload files but is there any way I can upload it to a specific folder in my firebase storage??

Comment: A folder in Cloud Storage is just a path with one or more `/` in it somewhere. Did you try specifying the path in that format, e.g. `"path/to/file.jpg"`?

Comment: so do i just do this in the put function `storage.child("IMAGE.jpeg").put("Folder_to_be_uploaded\\IMAGE.jpeg")`

Comment: No: `storage.child("Folder_to_be_uploaded/IMAGE.jpeg").put(...)`. There's an example of it here: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase?tab=readme-ov-file#put

Comment: Got it, works like butter now! Kinda got confused by the lack of elaboration in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the documentation of Pyrebase on [writing files](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase?tab=readme-ov-file#put), you can specify a path on the server where to write the file by specifying that path with slashes in the `child()` call. From the docs:

```
storage = firebase.storage()
# as admin
storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg")
```

This takes the local `example2.jpg` file and writes it into the `images` folder on Cloud Storage with name `example.jpg`.